# Using Skrollr with Dart

Tags: dart, skrollr, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to implement some scroll based animation in my Dart web application using Skrollr.js. So far I have the following in main():

```dart
main() {
  ScriptElement script = new ScriptElement()
    ..type = 'application/javascript'
    ..src = 'skrollr.min.js';
  document.body.children.add(script);
  ScriptElement script2 = new ScriptElement()
    ..type = 'application/javascript'
    ..innerHtml = 'var s = skrollr.init({forceHeight: false});';
  document.body.children.add(script2);

  js.context.callMethod('skrollr', ['init({forceHeight: false})']);
}
```

For some reason I'm getting the following errors when run:

```dart
Uncaught ReferenceError: skrollr is not defined and 
Exception: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'skrollr'
```

skroller.min.js has been placed in the app next to index.html so I'm looking for help on what is wrong here.

Also if the is a pure Dart alternative for scroll based animations I'd be happy to know of that as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it should be: `js.context['skrollr'].callMethod('init', [{'forceHeight': false}])`.

Comment: @Robert, just tried that and getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: skrollr is not defined' still.

Comment: you should use `document.body.append` or just add <script> to your html code.

Comment: Adding the the script tags to the html file helps but then I still get the error when trying to access the skrollr function from dart.

Comment: how does your code look like now?

Comment: added to index.html:      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var s = skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: false
        });
        </script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66356/discussion-between-robert-and-basheps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use:

```
import 'dart:js'; 

void main() { 
  void keyframe(element, name, direction) {
  } 

  context['skrollr'].callMethod('init', [{'keyframe': keyframe}]); 
}

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>skrollr</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skrollr.min.js"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script> 
    <script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

this works. no problem with it.